# How to add login link beside welcome message in magento 1.7

Tags: magento

I'm trying to move the "login" link in the toplinks beside the default welcome message.C:\xampp\htdocs\myhealthzone\app\design\frontend\default\myhealth\template\page\html\header.phtml in this I gave the code as

```
<p class="welcome-msg">
   <?php echo $this->__('Hi %s', Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getFirstname()); ?>
   <?php echo $this->getAdditionalHtml() ?>
</p>
```

but this is only for session use. Please update me with how to get the login link here instead of session.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
<p class="welcome-msg">
<?php $helper = Mage::helper('customer'); ?>
<?php if ($helper->isLoggedIn() : ?>
<?php echo $this->__('Hi %s', Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getFirstname()); ?>
<?php else :?>
<a href="<?php echo $helper->getLoginUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Login');?></a> 
<?php endif; ?>
<?php echo $this->getAdditionalHtml() ?>
</p>
```

Comment: probably a syntax error by me in line 3. Use `if ($helper->isLoggedIn()) : ?>` instead. Sorry

Comment: but what ever i update in the header.phtml file its not reflecting on frontend. even the `<p class="welcome-msg">
   <?php echo $this->__('Hi %s', Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getFirstname()); ?>
   <?php echo $this->getAdditionalHtml() ?>
</p>` also not working now.Before atleast it shows "hi" on the front end instead of "magento default welcome message" what might be the problem??

Comment: There can be many explanations for this. Can it be that the system falls back to the default template at `frontend/base/default/template/page/html/header.phtml`? Did you check the error logs for any possible exceptions? Can you set a breakpoint to the modified code and check with a debugger if there is a problem with the execution?

Comment: Excellent work... u r really my life savior thanks a million...it worked like a miracle...